# Sort NSMutableArray with objects with uniqueID

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I've looked around the web and know that one of the ways to sort an `NSMutableArray` is by using `sortUsingSelector:`. But I'm still a little shaky on exactly what needs to be done. I know that the comparator method should return `NSOrderedAscending` or `NSOrderedDescending` in order to do the sorting, but I need a little more help.

I have an array of Block objects. Each Block has a unique ID ranging from 1 to 200+. I'd like to sort the array based on the Block objects uniqueID. Is this possible?

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 221; i++) {
    Block *block = [[Block alloc] init];
    block.uniqueId = i;
    [array addObject:block];
    [block release];
}
```

Now, obviously this array is sorted after initialization, but I add and remove Blocks later, and would like to resort the array afterwards. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is using sort descriptors. They are based on properties within the object.
You can do it in one line like this:

```
NSArray* sorted =[array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"uniqueId" ascending:YES]]];
```

or create them separately

```
NSSortDescriptor* idDescriptor=[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"uniqueID" ascending:YES]
NSArray* descriptors=[NSArray arrayWithObject: idDescriptor];
NSArray* sortedArray=[array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: descriptors];
```

With this option you can specify multiple levels of sorting by adding multiple NSSortDescriptors to the descriptors array.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id o1, id o2) {
    int id1 = ((Block *)o1).uniqueId;
    int id2 = ((Block *)o2).uniqueId;

    if (id1 == id2) {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
    if (id1 < id2) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```